# Hibernate - filtering by associated property

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an `ExamResult` class which has a link back to it's parent `Exam`.

I wish to filter by a boolean property on exam result.

```
List<ExamResult> examResults = session
                    .createCriteria(ExamResult.class)
                    .createCriteria("exam") // 3.
                    .add( Restrictions.eq("primaryExam", Boolean.TRUE) ) // 4.
                    .list();
```

I can retrieve all rows correctly without lines 3 and 4 added. With these additional lines I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: not an association: exam
```

I'm unsure whether I'm going about this the right way. The [hibernate tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations) is unclear to me.

The relationship I used can be seen in [this tutorial](http://java-aap.blogspot.com/2006/04/hibernate-annotations-composite.html).

**ExamResult** has:

```
// bidirectional association! Needed to trick hibernate ;P
@Column(name="exam_id", nullable=false, updatable=false, insertable=false)
private Long exam;
```

**Exam** has

```
//----bidirectional association
@OneToMany(mappedBy="exam")
private final List<ExamResult> examResults = new ArrayList<ExamResult>();
```

Comment: even though you are using the tutorial, could you show your actual mapping so everyone can look over that? :)  thanks!

Comment: @Arthur Thomas - I've updated with the relevant associations.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the in your `ExamResult` mapping should be:

```
@Column(name="exam_id", nullable=false)
private Exam exam;
```

Otherwise, your criteria looks fine assuming you have a boolean property `primaryExam` in `Exam`.

Comment: Thanks - this now shows `org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: Exam column: exam_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")` - I presume the repeated column is to do with the hibernate trick in the tutorial.

Comment: Can you paste the complete ExamResult? Try removing the name="exam_id" part. If you are not mapping to an already existing database, it's useles. BTW, if an answer is usefull, dont forget to upvote or accept it :-).